# The methods setText() and getText() are undefined for the type String in Java?

Tags: java, calculator, eclipse-luna

I'm building a calculator with in Java by using Eclipse - Luna, but when adding the code of "Entering the number" I get two error messages as follow:

The Code:

```
    JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
    btn8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            String EnterNumber = TxtDisplay.getText() + btn8.getText();
            TxtDisplay.setText(EnterNumber );
        }
    });
    btn8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    btn8.setBounds(79, 137, 50, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn8);
```

The Error Messages:

```
The method getText() is undefined for the type String
The method setText(String) is undefined for the type String
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What is your `TxtDisplay`? Check whether it is  a String variable or a control on UI.

Comment: I guess you are wanting `TxtDisplay` to be a JTextField

Comment: Scary Wombat: Can I use JTextField for both of getText and setText

Comment: Yes, `JTextField` inherits from [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to display the content of TxtDisplay on GUI, that implies TxtDisplay has to be a [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html).

Look up your code you'll find `String TxtDisplay;` replace it by `JTextField TxtDisplay;`.

Once you do that you can access public methods of class JTextField such as `getText()` and `setText(String)`.

**Side note: Please next time choose a better title for your question, this is for your own benefit so our community can interact with you better**.

Answer (score 2):

Your TxtDisplay variable is a String which will explain the errors. 
If your TxtDisplay is displayable in the frame, you need to change it to type JTextField.

```
String TxtDisplay;
```

to

```
JTextField TxtDisplay;
```